# I have a df of words and I want to know if they are in English dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a function like this. I have a data frame of words, and I want to test if those words are in the English dictionary or not. If yes, return True, if not return False.

The dataframe looks like below
words
cat
dog
mark
lillly

If I run through the function, I want to return a new col

```
words  is_english
cat    true
dog    true
mark   true
lillly false
```

my function looks like below:

```
from nltk.corpus import words as nltk_words
def is_english_word(word):
    # creation of this dictionary would be done outside of 
    #     the function because you only need to do it once.
    dictionary = dict.fromkeys(nltk_words.words(), None)
    try:
        x = dictionary[word]
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

call the function

```
df.apply(lambda x: is_english_word(df['words']), axis=1)
```

can anyone tell me where did I get it wrong? it couldn't return the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a custom function nor `apply` (this is slow), you can use `pandas.isin` and a `set` of the words to speed up the process:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import words as nltk_words
words = set(nltk_words.words())

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['cat', 'dog', 'mark', 'lillly']})

df['is_english'] = df['words'].isin(words)
```

Output:

```
    words  is_english
0     cat        True
1     dog        True
2    mark        True
3  lillly       False
```